# Wordpress Login & Registeration System Like http://www.damnlag.com/

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I came across http://www.damnlag.com/ yesterday and I have no idea how they have managed to build that kind of user sign up system using wordpress. how have they integrated the login form in the main website and how have they changed the look and fields of the registration form.

Is it some plugin i'm not aware of? or have they messed around with the wordpress code.

If anyone knows about this please let me know.

Appreciate your help,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of actions/filters in [wp-login.php](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress/trunk/wp-login.php). They probably just used a combination of those and some fancy CSS. For the login box on the front page, there's are [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) (under Login/Logout tags) that allow those to be embedded in the template.